# Finding duplicate points within an arraylist of points

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to delete all the duplicate points within two array lists. Each list is created by finding which country links to which country, if they link then it creates a new point in both arrays at the same time.

The idea is so that I can loop though the size of both arrays (Or size of one) and draw lines between the points.

Problem at the moment is that it's not deleting the points or it deletes them all.

I have the following Arrays

```
//Different values of course.
Array1 = [Point[1,5]],[Point[1,5]],[Point[1,5]][Point[1,5]]
Array2 = [Point[1,5]],[Point[1,5]],[Point[1,5]][Point[1,5]]
```

Here's the code that deletes the duplicate arrays out:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> checkDuplicatePoints(ArrayList<Point> Array1, ArrayList<Point> Array2)
{
    for(int index1 = 0; index1 < Array1.size(); index1++)
    {
        for(int index2 = 0; index2 < Array2.size(); index2++)
        {
            //So not the same position in the list.
            if(index1 != index2)
            {
                if(
                    Array1.get(index1).x == Array2.get(index2).x &&
                    Array1.get(index1).y == Array2.get(index2).y
                )
                {
                    Array1.remove(index1);
                    Array2.remove(index2);
                    checkDuplicatePoints(Array1, Array2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> n2DPointArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();

    n2DPointArray.add(Array1);
    n2DPointArray.add(Array2);

    return n2DPointArray;
}
```

Comment: If you don't care about changing the order of elements in the ArrayList, you can can sort it and quickly remove duplicates. It sounds like you are creating a graph. As an alternative solution, you might want to look into standard programming data structures for graphs.

Comment: I'm not creating a graph, it's for linkages on an actual display map. The order must be the same :-(

Comment: Takking the 2 arrays you provide in your question, should only 1 point be left or one in each array? It's unclear what you're trying to acheive.

Comment: @AbakizMyth Such a structure with links is called a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)). It's easy to confuse this with graphing points, lines, curves, etc. from Algebra if you are unfamiliar with graph theory. Graph data structures are very common in computer programming and are an extremely useful tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i underStand your problem may be you should look into these code and example

```
public class test {
public static void main(String ap[])
{

    List<Point> mList1 =new ArrayList<Point>();
    List<Point> mList2 =new ArrayList<Point>();
    Point mPoint1 = new Point(1, 2);
    Point mPoint2 = new Point(2, 3);

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        mList1.add(mPoint1);
        mList1.add(mPoint2);
    }
    Point mPoint3 = new Point(1, 2);
    Point mPoint4 = new Point(3, 4);

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        mList2.add(mPoint3);
        mList2.add(mPoint4);
    }

    System.out.println(mList1);
    //System.out.println(mList2);
    new test().removingDuplicatesQID(mList1, mList2);
    System.out.println(mList1);
}
public void removingDuplicatesQID(List<Point> list1,List <Point> list2)
{
    Set<Point> uniqueEntries = new HashSet<Point>();
    for (Iterator iter = list1.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
    {
        Point element = (Point) iter.next();
        if (!uniqueEntries.add(element))
            /* if current element is a duplicate, remove it */
            iter.remove();
    }
    uniqueEntries.clear();
}
}
```

OUTPUT

```
    System.out.println(mList1);
```

[java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2], java.awt.Point[x=2,y=3], java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2], java.awt.Point[x=2,y=3], java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2], java.awt.Point[x=2,y=3]]

//after removing duplicate from arrayList1

```
        System.out.println(mList1);
```

[java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2], java.awt.Point[x=2,y=3]]

I hope this could help you or ..else be more specific to your problem and result you need out of your array list

Comment: I can give you my country linker code if you wish? I'm struggling to implement this, it's not working :-(

Comment: sure .. and give explanation and detail and output requisite so that i can get into your problem and try to solve it...........

Answer (score 0):

Put them into a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Sets don't allow duplicate entries.

EDIT:
Another possibility: Don't add them in the first place.

```
void addPoint( Point newPoint )
{
    if( !array1.contains(newPoint) )
    {
        array1.add(newPoint);
    }
}
```

YET ANOTHER EDIT:

Now, that it is clearer: Why not create your own Datastructure for this. Let's call it `CountryLink`.

It would have two `Point`s and overrides `equals()` in that it returns true, if two instances of it have the same two points, no matter if as start or end. Then you can put it easily into an ArrayList like shown above. Or into a Set which automatically will reject duplicates.

Comment: Can you have a set of Points?

Comment: Yes, you can. But I'm not sure anymore, if this is what you want. I thought you wanted to delete duplicates inside each Array. But your code seems to do something quite different.

Comment: Can we assume that 1. Both arrays have the same size at the beginning? 2. A "duplicate" is a Point that is in Array1 **and** Array2 but not in the same index?

Comment: The arrays are the same size, they contain different points. We want to find out if any of the points of the same position in the array are not the same as the points in another position.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Let's say we are looking at index 1 of Array1 and there we find Point A. Now you want to go through Array2 and delete each occurrence of Point A in there except if it is at index 1. Correct?

Comment: I basically have a list of countries, each country has access via say airport, boats, cars etc. These lines are draw by giving 2 points (Start and End). Problem is each country can go both ways so the lines are drawn twice (which isn't good because they are dotted). I want to delete the second set of lines.

Comment: What are you trying to do from your question that you want to delete those point from Array1 and Array2 which are in both list ..........

Comment: @Vipin Sahu: He has a list of directed Graphs and wants to ignore direction. Then A->B and B->A would be the "same" and thus a duplicate. And he wants to eliminate those.

Comment: Well the idea is to delete them from both lists, because each list holds a corresponding point, them I'm left with just one line.

Comment: Funny you say that, my class is already called CountryLink :P. I'm implementing this method as speak speak.

Comment: This work's but it doesn't work on the first and last entries of the ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if i understood your question right, but here is a solution for making a list, which contains only the distinct elements (its not very efficient):

```
private ArrayList<Point> distinctPoints(ArrayList<Point> first, ArrayList<Point> second)
{
    ArrayList<Point> distinct = new ArrayList<Point>();

    for(Point point : first)
        if(!distinct.contains(point))
            distinct.add(point);

    for(Point point : second)
        if(!distinct.contains(point))
            distinct.add(point);

    return distinct;
}
```

And another one for finding the duplicates:

```
private ArrayList<Point> duplicatePoints(ArrayList<Point> first, ArrayList<Point> second)
{
    ArrayList<Point> duplicate = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Point> distinct = new ArrayList<Point>();

    for(Point point : first)
        if(distinct.contains(point))
            duplicate.add(point);
        else 
            distinct.add(point)   

    for(Point point : second)
        if(distinct.contains(point))
            duplicate.add(point);
        else 
            distinct.add(point)  

    return duplicate;
}
```

If you are not using the `java.awt.Point` class for this, then your Point class should have an overriden `equals()` and look something like this:

```
public class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {this.x=x; this.y=y;}
    public Point(){this(0,0);}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null) return false;
        if(obj == this) return true;
        if(obj.getClass() != Point.class) return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        return other.x==this.x && other.y==this.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work with Points? How does it match Point.x and Point.y?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Point has an overriden equals() method. It compares one Point with another, and returns true, if their x and y coordinates match. The List's containts() method checks if the list "contains" something using this equals() function.

Comment: Are you using the java.awt.Point class? If not, then check the answer again

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I follow your idea but why not use an Iterator?

For Example:

```
for (Iterator iter = yourList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
 {
    Object item = iter.next();

    if (YOUR_CONDITION_HERE)
    {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you iterating over the two lists and removing the duplicates from both of them?

Comment: Yes he is, see comments in my answer.